# HTML files downloading rather than executing

Tags: html

Trying to get a client's site up.  The HTML files keep downloading rather than executing.

I've done a MIME check and the files appear to be text/html. I recreated the database admin, password and made sure that there was a connection between the script and the MySQL database. Permissions seem to be fine and the `index.html` is executable, permissions 755. Not sure where to turn next.

Comment: "I recreated the database admin..." - have you tried this without any "database" and a simple `test.html` file? By "download", presumably you mean you are prompted with a "Save As..." dialog? "index.html is executable, permissions 755" - "index.html" should not be executable and neither should it be 0755 - those are the permissions you would perhaps expect for an internal directory.

Comment: Can you tell us the procedure you did when doing the MIME check? I suspect your checking the config file in a text viewer when that's fine but it doesn't necessary mean that the config is being read. Have you done a PHP Info check?

Answer (score 1):

When a web browser offers to download a file rather than open it, it is generally because the headers are incorrect.    It sounds like you already checked the "Content-Type" header, but you also need to check the "Content-Disposition" header.

An easy way to check the headers on your page is to use the command line tool `curl`:

```
curl -s --head 'http://example.com/'
```

The "Content-Type" header should start with "text/html".   There should be **no** "Content-Disposition" header.  If you see something like this, you will need to configure your server to remove it:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.html"
```